# how to use tag helpers to do a post request and update part of the view without reloading the page

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a question about MVC5/6. I want to do a simple POST request using tag helpers, sending some information to the server and getting a string that must be shown to the user inside the form block, updating part of the view without reloading the page.

I know how to do this using jquery and ajax, but I want to do it using only tag-helpers. I found a solution using @model, and it works, the problem is that model is already being used in other part of the page.

This is my code so far:

```
<form class="custom-form" asp-action="InsertCommentNews" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<h3 class="titleForm">Comentar</h3>
<h4>@ViewBag.ReturnUrl</h4>
<hr />
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="author">Nombre</label>
    <input id="author" name="author" type="text" class="form-control custom-form-input" placeholder="Nombre" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment">Comentario</label>
    <input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" class="form-control custom-form-input" placeholder="Comentario" />
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <button type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>&nbsp; Enviar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot do it just using tag helpers. In order to get something from the server after the html has been sent to the client you need to use ajax if you do not want a refresh/redirect.

Comment: not even using the data-ajax tags? :(

Comment: That is ajax! (and its obsolete) - far better to use the `$.ajax()` methods